# Resetting application window size

Tags: macos, applications, window-manager

I would like to know how to reset a user set window size for an application to the one chosen by the developer. Are these settings usually stored in some plist file?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Application, but mostly it's stored in the `defaults` database. You can check for example **Mail.app** with:

```
defaults read com.apple.mail DefaultWindowState
```

If You do not know the `key` just grep with "window" the output from `defaults read BUNDLE_ID`
where `BUNDLE_ID` is Your application bundle identifier which can be read like this:

```
APP_PATH="/Applications/Mail.app"
defaults read "$APP_PATH/Contents/Info.plist" CFBundleIdentifier
```

You can try to change keys in plists using `defaults` command or locate plist file in `~/Library/Preferences` directory and change it manually.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by"You can try to change keys in plists using defaults command or locate plist file in ~/Library/Preferences directory and change it manually".... Should I pass default in the string area of the plist for resetting to the default size or?

Comment: @Caspert I think You can just delete the key with `defaults delete BUNDLE KEY`